# Unable to add the class object to the entity framework model

Tags: asp.net, json, entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I'm creating a post API to store data in the database. I created a class and added the class members data to the model, but I am getting the error

> giving error - cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'

```
public ActionResult AddTemprature([FromBody]tempretureViewModel paramTemplate)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        using (smartpondEntities DB = new smartpondEntities())
        {
            WebApi.Temperature temptable = new WebApi.Temperature();
            // and you need paramTemplate props to template object
            DB.Temperatures.Add(temptable);
            DB.SaveChanges();
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {

    }
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public  class tempretureViewModel
{

    public decimal? temp1 { get; set; }
    public decimal? PHValue { get; set; }
    public decimal? DOValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime? currentTime { get; set; }
}
```

WebApiConfig

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {


        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not about asp.net, json entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2. its about c#. WebApi.Controllers.tempretureViewModel' and'WebApi.Temperature'" different types.

```
public ActionResult AddTemprature([FromBody]tempretureViewModel paramTemplate)
        {
            try
            {
                currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                using (smartpondEntities DB = new smartpondEntities())
                {
                    WebApi.Temperature temptable = new WebApi.Temperature();
                    // and you need to set paramTemplate props to template object

                    DB.Temperatures.Add(temptable);
                    DB.SaveChanges();
                    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {

            }
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Update : WebApiConfig.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Clear();
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Comment: giving error - cannot convert from 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings'

Comment: should i add it in register method ?

Comment: project is not building , showing same error.updated my question, where i have shown how i added in register method.

Answer (score 0):

use namespace above class instead off using with class
I have marked that with bold.
**WebApi.Temperature temptable = new WebApi.Temperature();**
add name space

```
public ActionResult AddTemprature([FromBody]tempretureViewModel paramTemplate)
{
    try
    {
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        using (smartpondEntities DB = new smartpondEntities())
        {
            **WebApi.Temperature temptable = new WebApi.Temperature();**
            // and you need paramTemplate props to template object
            DB.Temperatures.Add(temptable);
            DB.SaveChanges();
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {

    }
    return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public  class tempretureViewModel
{

    public decimal? temp1 { get; set; }
    public decimal? PHValue { get; set; }
    public decimal? DOValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime? currentTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: sorry i didn't get you which namespace i need to add in my snippet

Comment: using WebApi;


Declare class like this
Temperature temptable = new Temperature();